# nginx and mp4/webm files not viewable

Tags: nginx, mp4

I just setup a vps and installed nginx. I've got it serving files (html, jpg, etc) but when I attempt to view or see in the directory listing mp4 and webm files they go 403 and the directory listing doesn't even show them.

Permissions on all files (html, jpg, mp4, webm) are all the same 644.

Nginx is compiled with --with-httpd_mp4_module.

I tried adding location lines and variables for buffer sizes in the conf and even moved the mp4's around but nothing seem to work.

It's only the mp4/webm files that seem to be invisible.

Here's the error in the log:
2015/09/05 13:23:53 [error] 10283#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/video/test.mp4" failed (13: Permission denied), client: x.x.x.x, server: _, request: "GET /video/test.mp4 HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.x.x.xx"

Comment: Check the permissions on the file.

Comment: "Permissions on all files (html, jpg, mp4, webm) are all the same 644."

Answer (score 0):

So this ended up being a problem with SELinux permissions. In the end I switched over to Apache because the instructions on how to adjust SELinux didn't work for me on nginx but that's just because I didn't have nginx specific instructions.

If anyone is having trouble getting specific files types like mp4 or webm to be publicly viewable in nginx or apache and you know the file permissions are correct look into SELinux's permissions as well.

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux